# Machine learning - introducing a bias in training data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have data which I'm using for training. When I feed it into my neural network, I get a 3% error on that data.

I know that this data has certain overrepresentations - class 5 has roughly one tenth the examples of the other classes, for example.

My assignment states that I can improve the detection rate by biasing the training data - that is, by removing or duplicating certain data. However, it seems to me that the neural network should be able to automatically account for this, and any modifications I've made have only drastically reduced the network's accuracy.

I'm especially confused because the way I'm supposed to judge whether or not the network has improved is by testing it against the *original* training partition. It seems to me that using a modified version of the training partition to train will always give you a worse detection rate on the original training partition, but the assignment seems to indicate otherwise.

Since this is homework, I'd appreciate tips and not direct answers.

Comment: You may want to migrate this question to `stats`

Comment: If the classes in data are not of equal representation, then "Accuracy" as an evaluation metric can be tricky. you can check out "**log loss**" as an evaluation metric. 

You can train the data using a very simple approach called **n-fold cross-validation**. and create a **validation set**. Test against the validation set, and choose your hyper-parameters. This approach does not hinder your quest for generalizability

Comment: @iratzhash log loss has the exact same characteristic in terms of classes imbalance as accuracy (as this is just accuracy + probability estimate, there is no balancing of any kind). Furthermore Daniel is not asking about hyperparameters selection but rather about ways of altering the training procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that using a modified version of the training partition to train will always give you a worse detection rate on the original training partition, but the assignment seems to indicate otherwise.

In short it is not true. Training set is something which helps you minimize the empirical risk (error on the trianing set). On the other hand you are trying to minimize generalization risk (error on test set) and here - adding some additional bias (in many forms) might actually help as it prevents you from overfitting. In particular, when dealing with high imbalance of classes, empirical risk minimization might lead to complete ignoring of the minority (in particular in SGD based approaches where single update might just be not enough to get away from the stronger attractors of bigger classes), thus biasing (in some way) might improve the overall classification.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to bias? Should I overrepresent classes which are underrepresented?

Comment: it depends what is your evaluation metric. For neural network "overrepresenting" is actually the same as simply changing the probability you use during SGD - simply by making a small class more probable to be selected. There are no exact rules for "how much", unless you have some very specific metric to optimize (such as GMean/BAC)